# Why doesn't this simple JavaScript if statement work?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

This if statement doesn't work. I would expect it to write "if" as the variable should be empty. Or failing that I would expect "else" but there are neither

You can also see it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pRJT2/) in full not working glory

*I think JSFiddle maybe having problems at the moment*

```
checkforthread();

function checkforthread() { // Check to see if it is a new or existing chat

// Set the variable
        var existingthread = "";

      document.write("test");

      if (typeof(existingthread) == 'undefined' || variable == null) {
            document.write("if");
            gotostage3();   
            }
          else {
            document.write("else");
            gotostage3();   
          }
}
```

Comment: First guess is that `variable` is `undefined`

Comment: You haven't defined `variable`.  Did you intend to check if `existingthread == null` instead?

Comment: open your developer tool bar and check console.If you do you will see the error "variable is not defined".

Comment: By the way, `typeof` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: Look. At. The. Console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I assume that you mistyped and that `variable` is supposed to be `existingthread`, then what you are doing wrong is that `existingthread` is neither `undefined` nor `null`, it is an empty string!

you could simplify your `if` clause by just saying `if (existingthread) { ... }`, if I am guessing correctly what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, if you try to take the value of an undefined symbol, you get a `ReferenceError`. That's what's happening here. `variable` is completely undefined, and so trying to take its value (so you can compare it with `null`) is failing with a `ReferenceError`. You can see this in the Dev Tools of your browser:

[image]

This aborts the script code being run, since it's not caught.

If for some reason you need to check if a symbol is defined, there *is* a way to do that: The `typeof` operator, which you're already using:

```
if (typeof existingthread == 'undefined' || typeof variable == 'undefined') {
```

If you apply `typeof` to a symbol you haven't defined, it doesn't throw an error; instead, you get back the string `"undefined"`.

---

Note that `typeof` is an operator, not a function; no need to wrap its operand in parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

`variable` is `undefined` and that's the same error being shown in JSFiddle.